# WWW::Mechanize::Firefox -- connection tme out

Tags: perl, firefox, web-scraping

I use perl version 5.14.2 (I think active) on a windows 32 machine with firefox version 18.

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
 use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;

 my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new(
      activate => 1, # bring the tab to the foreground
 );

  $mech->get('https://familysearch.org/search/collection/results#count=20&query=%2Bevent_place_level_1%3ACalifornia%20%2Bevent_place_level_2%3A%22San%20Diego%22%20%2Bbirth_year%3A1923-1923~%20%2Bgender%3AM%20%2Brace%3AWhite&      collection_id=2000219',':content_file'
  'main.html');


  1;
```

I get the error:
command timed-out at C:/Perl/site/lib/MozRepl/Client.pm line 186

I would greatly appreciate any help fixing this error.

However, if I run the following, it works:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
```

Under Tool, I see MozRepl.  I clicked ActivateStart.

Comment: @MooingDuck - I'd guess it's his GET call that's timing out. That would make this too localized, since there'd be nothing wrong with the code itself. But if that's the reason, there really should be a comment saying so.

Comment: @mooingDuck Wrong, guess. It's the communication between the module and the applicaiton. This user is a spammer. This question has been posted on and off for years by them on OpenSuse and Perlmonks https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/499167-ruby-extensions-where-do-i-get-them-for-opensuse-13-1?p=2651906#post2651906